# JQuery: do something when div is hidden fails

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to change the text colour of the h2 title with id `ticketSearchTitle` when the `ticketSearch` div is  hidden. But the piece of code I'm using to do that seems to break it entirely (i.e: no pointer icon on title, cannot hide div).

Div structure:

```
  <h2 id="ticketSearchTitle" >SEARCH</h2>
  <div id="ticketSearch"><div>
```

Full code:

```
$("h2#ticketSearchTitle").css({'cursor':'pointer', 'display':'inline'});

  $("h2#ticketSearchTitle").click(function(){

      $("#ticketSearch").toggle('slow');

       //change h2 text to show that is is inactive
       if ($("h2#ticketSearch").is(':hidden')){
          $("#ticketSearchTitle").css('color','#D3D3D3')
      }

  });
```

JQuery snippet that breaks the code:

```
 //change h2 text to show that is inactive
       if $("h2#ticketSearch").is(':hidden'){
          $("#ticketSearchTitle").css('color','#D3D3D3')
      }
```

Comment: You lack parens around your `if`.

Comment: oops, was included in original code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do these two sequences right after one another, you cause a problem because the toggle just starts an animation and that animation is not finished when you immediately check if the element is hidden:

```
$("#ticketSearch").toggle('slow');

//change h2 text to show that is is inactive
if ($("h2#ticketSearch").is(':hidden')){
   $("#ticketSearchTitle").css('color','#D3D3D3')
}
```

You have a couple options.  You can either check to see if it's hidden BEFORE the animation and act on the pre-animation value (know it will be toggled).  Or, you can use an actual animation and a completion function so the rest of the code only runs when the toggle is done.

For example, if you want the second part of the code to run after the animation is done, you can do this:

```
$("#ticketSearch").toggle('slow', function() {
    //change h2 text to show that is is inactive
    if ($("#ticketSearch").is(':hidden')){
       $("#ticketSearchTitle").css('color','#D3D3D3')
    }
});
```

FYI, there's no reason to use `"h2#ticketSearch"` as your selector.  `"#ticketSearch"` would be faster and generate the same result.

Comment: `ticketSearch` is a div not a `h2` he is checking for `$("h2#ticketSearch").is(':hidden')` but there does not exists `<h2 id="ticketSearch"></h2>`

Comment: Thanks. It was an an oversight on my part when I did `$("h2#ticketSearch").is(':hidden')`. It was always meant to be `$("#ticketSearch").is(':hidden')`

Answer (score 2):

have you forgot to add the brackets for `if`

```
if ($("h2#ticketSearch").is(':hidden')){
```

Answer (score 2):

You have forgot 2 things

1) you forgot brackets around the if

```
      if ($("h2#ticketSearch").is(':hidden')){
```

2) Your `ticketSearch` is a div not a `h2`

```
       if $("h2#ticketSearch").is(':hidden'){ //wrong
       if $("div#ticketSearch").is(':hidden'){ //correct
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/KKgTU/4/

Comment: Ha, nice catch on the h2. No one else noticed that one.